# Unsupported graphics card and no USB 3 on old desktop. Should I upgrade the hardware or replace the whole PC?

Tags: graphics-cards, usb

I have a machine license for Microsoft Windows 10 Pro on my old desktop (originally installed with Windows 7), which I got during the free-upgrade period from Microsoft.  However, when I upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10, I discovered that even though I could get the default Microsoft drivers for the integrated graphics, the manufacturer (AMD) did not have any proprietary Windows 10 drivers available for the old integrated graphics card, which makes it difficult to run PC games on Windows 10 that need the proprietary AMD drivers.

Since all I need to run PC games on the desktop is a supported graphics card, it would be cheaper to just buy a dedicated graphics card for the old PC (which would have much better performance than integrated graphics anyway) rather than buying a new computer altogether.  However, it looks like a new graphics card would also require a new power supply as well due to the higher power requirements.  I would also like to add USB 3.0 to the PC (it currently only has USB 2.0), which looks to be doable, especially with a new power supply that has Molex to support USB 3.0.

My question is are there going to be any major disadvantages in trying to save some money by upgrading the hardware on the old PC (new power supply, new graphics card, plus a USB 3.0 card), versus simply buying a new Windows 10 desktop PC instead?  The biggest difference that I can see is that the newer desktops have PCIe 3.0 instead of PCIe 2.0, which seems to be limited to no more than 2 GB of video RAM.  So if I bought a new desktop with integrated graphics and PCIe 3.0, I could still upgrade it later to add dedicated graphics, but would not be limited to 2 GB or less of video RAM.  Ideally, I would like to keep the desktop PC futureproof until at least 2020 (10 years from its manufacture date).

Other than having a graphics card that is not supported on Windows 10, and not having USB 3.0, the desktop PC is a pretty good one.  It has a 3.0-GHz quadcore processor, 8 GB RAM (upgradeable to 16 GB), 1.5 TB of internal HDD storage, a LightScribe multidrive (which doesn't even exist any more, though I still have LightScribe discs that I can burn using free software), plus the available machine license for Windows 10 Pro.

If I upgrade the hardware, I would like to also get an HDMI UHD (4K) monitor if possible, as well as add a Blu-Ray drive on the USB 3.0, which I think should be supported.  That way I can use the desktop as a multimedia PC for Blu-Ray videos in 4K UHD.  Do you think that 4K gaming would be doable though on this PC, even with the 2 GB of dedicated graphics RAM plus the 8 GB of system RAM?

Here are the exact specifications on the hardware (HP p6716f):

https://support.hp.com/document/c02631315/

https://support.hp.com/document/c02560084/

https://www.game-debate.com/motherboard/index.php?mot_id=1480

Here are the hardware I am considering adding:

https://www.bestbuy.com/site/thermaltake-smart-series-650w-bronze-power-supply-black/8733872.p/

<s>https://www.bestbuy.com/site/visiontek-500w-internal-power-supply-black/4698305.p/</s>

Is 500 watts too much power?  The new graphics card would only need 300 watts.

https://www.bestbuy.com/site/evga-nvidia-geforce-gt-710-2gb-ddr3-pci-express-2-0-graphics-card-black/4961400.p/

or

https://www.bestbuy.com/site/pny-nvidia-geforce-gt-730-2gb-ddr3-pci-express-2-0-graphics-card-black/6164149.p/

Which is better though, the GeForce 710 or the GeForce 730?  They look to be very similar to me, other than the price.

https://www.bestbuy.com/site/visiontek-4-port-usb-3-0-pci-express-expansion-card/7370106.p/

https://www.visiontek.com/4-port-usb-3-0-pcie-internal-card.html

Are there any other upgrades I could make to the old desktop to improve performance or capabilities?

<s>https://www.bestbuy.com/site/sandisk-ultra-500gb-internal-sata-solid-state-drive-for-laptops/5969505.p/</s>

I already have a 1 TB HDD plus a 0.5 TB HDD, for 1.5 TB total.  I don't think that replacing the 0.5 TB HDD with a 0.5 TB SSD will be worth the expense though.  It looks like SSDs require SATA 3, so that is probably another disadvantage of sticking with the older PC that has SATA 2.

I should add also that I do not really know how to replace all these things myself.  I am assuming that I can figure it out by watching YouTube videos.  Though I do have an anti-static kit already, that I picked up a while back on clearance when RadioShack was going out of business.  Otherwise I can have it all installed at my local computer shop for just US$30 in labor cost.

Comment: Something else completely different I am debating is whether maybe I should just forget about the desktop altogether and get myself a Windows 10 gaming laptop with dedicated graphics.  I already have a Windows 10 laptop though (with integrated graphics, but it has USB 3.0 and HDMI), so I am not sure if that is really worth it.  I can't do high-definition video editing on my current laptop though.

Comment: This is a really broad question. It looks like you are asking what to do: either buy a new desktop computer or buy a new GPU, PSU, and a USB 3.0 card for the existing one. That question is something you are going to have to answer, as it is asking for an opinion. Secondly, on top of that question, you also mention a Blu-ray drive and a 4K monitor. Every component in your question is on-topic here, as long as you break them up into their own questions. Please have a look at our [Question Quality Guidelines](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/205/60) if you have any questions.

Comment: I think you should ask this on Super User. AFAIK, there's nothing wrong with the question itself, its just on the wrong forum.

Comment: Just found these two links, which I think might answer my question.  Lifewire.com recommends upgrading an old desktop if the cost of upgrading is less than half of the cost to replace it.  https://www.lifewire.com/upgrade-or-replace-desktop-pc-832712/  https://www.komando.com/tips/12058/

Comment: It looks like the total cost to upgrade will be over $130, versus the cost of replacing the desktop (with something similar but Windows-10 compatible) would be only $278.  So it looks like I might be better off after all just getting a new desktop.  There are also apparently a lot of ominous warnings about continuing to use hard-disk drives that are going on eight years old (the desktop was manufactured in 2010).

Answer (score 1):

Here's what it sounds to me like it boils down to.

You could buy a graphics card and power supply. One benefit of that is that, if you decide to replace your computer down the line, you can move the graphics card over and not have to pay for one again for a while. Installing a graphics card is very straightforward. Installing the power supply is pretty much straightforward, but it's a little more of a pain. I'd say that $30 is very reasonable to have someone else do this for you.

You could also buy a new computer. Here, you'd be getting the benefits of the latest hardware. Also, depending on the games you're wanting to play, integrated graphics have gotten good and you might be able to avoid buying a graphics card for a while longer.

Here's what I'd suggest. Since you haven't done any of this before, I'd take the specs of your current machine and your list of parts down to the computer store and ask their advice. I'd give it 100% chance they're only too happy to talk it over with you and give you tips as well. If, based on their feedback, the project seems like too much cost or effort, go with the new machine. (And consider buying it from them!)

Final point: I haven't looked much into your parts list but my gut feeling is that a 500W power supply is too small. I know graphics cards have gotten better but, when you're picking a power supply, you want to look at the power requirements for all your components (so basically, 250W from your current machine and 300W for the graphics card, leaving you at 550W) and then pick a power supply for which your power requirement is at 80% of the maximum rating of the supply. So you probably want a power supply that is rated for 650-700W.

Comment: If I choose to upgrade now and continue to take good care of the desktop, hopefully it will last for another 3 years at least. However, by then I think a PCIe 2.0 graphics card with 2 GB VRAM is going to be woefully outdated for gaming (even right now, 4 GB would be my preference if I had PCIe 3.0), so I doubt I would want to transfer it if I could afford a graphics card that is faster and with more VRAM.  Also, PCIe 4.0 was just released this year (2017), but PCIe 3.0 cards support up to 11 GB VRAM, vs. PCIe 2.0 cards support only up to 2 GB VRAM.

Comment: "The benefits of the latest hardware."  That is essentially what I am trying to figure out.  What exactly are the benefits of a newer PC vs. an upgraded old PC?  The only differences I have found so far are support for more VRAM with PCIe 3.0 and support for SSDs with SATA 3.  Are there other benefits?  Can I really compare a 7-year-old 3.0-GHz quadcore CPU with a modern quadcore CPU?

Comment: The desktop currently has a 250-watt power supply with integrated graphics.  If the dedicated graphics card requires 300 watts, then I need to add those numbers together?  I do not know how much power the USB 3.0 card requires, but I don't think it would be much of an issue since I have an external powered USB 3.0 hub to connect high-speed devices to.  I can already connect that to USB 2.0 (with reduced speed), but I want the higher bandwidth.

Comment: 650 W is the cheapest power supply that is over 550 W. The USB 3.0 card actually comes with a SATA-to-Molex adapter, so I don't think I need Molex on the power supply.  https://www.bestbuy.com/site/thermaltake-smart-series-650w-bronze-power-supply-black/8733872.p/

Comment: For power, yeah, you add all those together. The power rating listed by a power supply is the max power it was designed for. They achieve best efficiency at 80% output for sustained, typical use. If you get one that's too small, you won't be able to source enough power, but likewise, you don't want to get one that's too big. It's not as big a problem as too small, but it's not what you want (and also it's more expensive).

Comment: As far as benefits, CPUs have gotten faster and the number of processors has increased, so that affects everything. Because of that, and also because of, I'm sure, a whole bunch of reasons that are totally not my wheelhouse, integrated graphics is not the joke it was years ago, and in fact, you can increasingly get by without a dedicated graphics card. Or certainly, you can put off buying one for a while.